# Use a keychain password for a environment variable on Mac

Tags: bash, shell

Oftentimes, we need to have a password in an environment variable in a developement environment. But I like to put my dotfiles on GitHub so that I can have a highly portable setup.

However, it's definitely not a good idea to keep any password in those dotfiles for the reason of putting it on GitHub, or just in general.

Mac comes with keychain which would encrypt and store passwords.
How can I make use of that to keep passwords and set it in the environment variable?

In particular, a shell script I can put in file [.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example) that will be loaded when I open a new Bash session.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a password item in your keychain. `AWS_DATABASE_PASSWORD` below is the account name instead of the keychain item name.

Put this script in your *.bashrc* file.

```
get_pw () {
  security find-generic-password -ga "$1" -w
}
export AWS_DATABASE_PASSWORD="$(get_pw AWS_DATABASE_PASSWORD)"
```

Comment: If the account name can have spaces, you'd better quote `"$1"` in the function

Comment: Be aware that it is possible to see the environment of a process with `ps -E`, which could expose the password.

Comment: @chepner thanks for pointing that out. I would imagine only using this on my local machine, and it would usually be protected by password. any scenario you can imagine causing insecurity?